# is http cookie the right place for storing user information

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies

Scenario:
I want to call an external api for authentication and then store the response in session so that any subsequent requests I make could use that information to do certain checks.

I am using Laravel and it offers you the option to store your session data in cookies. Are they safe to store user details, if they are retrieved from an external API? Any security risks? Is that a good solution?

Comment: Really, you might want to consider using JSON Web Tokens instead.

But NEVER store sensitive data in a cookie or a JWT. No passwords, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, What if i wanted to store user Id and OAUTH token ?

Comment: That depends on your app. If user id doesn't compromise information, sure. But maybe store those in the database and then, in the cookie, just store the row id for their session data.

Comment: It's usually better to store session data on the server.